# Beautiful soup returns empty while using class name to filter datas

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, dynamic-class

Im trying to retrieve the product names, weight and price in a list from the following site.

https://www.licious.in/seafood

my code to find the products list :

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  URL = 'https://www.licious.in/seafood'
  r = requests.get(URL)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

  productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_="card")

  productlinks = []

  for card in productlist:
        for link in card.find_all('a', href=True):
  print(link['href'])
```

Can I use css selector for the product prices and product weight ?

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues here:

1. Missing indentation
2. Product images you are trying to get with `soup.find_all("div", {"class": "product_image"})` are `img` elements, not `div`
3. `img1` object received by `item.find("img")` is not printable.
   This should work better:

```py
import requests,
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.licious.in/seafood'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
product_list = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "item-details"})

for item in product_list:

    product_names = item.find_all("div", {"class":  "item-title"})
# I see no point where detail_link_h2, detail_link_h3 and detail_link_h4 are defined so this will not work
#print(detail_link_h2 + ", " + detail_link_h3 + ", " + detail_link_h4)

product_images = soup.find_all("img", {"class": "product_image"})

for image in product_images:

    img1 = image.find("img")
#    print(img1)
```

Comment: I made some changes to the code in the question to atleast filter out the product names, but it returns nothing.

Comment: maybe because `product_names` is a list of web elements while you need to iterate over the list and extract the texts from each element?

Comment: I tried it using that and tried getting the weight and price using regex, but still it returns nothing.

Comment: Please show us that your code. How can we know why your code didn't work without seeing that code?

Comment: Sorry edited just now in the question.